# ODBC Error: Driver not capable

Tags: vb.net, odbc, 32bit-64bit, ibm-midrange

I'm establishing an ODBC connection to our AS/400 in an app I'm developing. It simply does a `DELETE` and then an `INSERT`. Nothing crazy or complicated. Everything works great on my 64-bit Windows 7 Pro desktop (UPDATE: no longer true) but when I try to run the app on my 32-bit laptop for a presentation, I get the following error:

> ERROR [S1C00] [Micro Focus][Rumba Data Access][S1023934]Driver not
>   capable. SQLSetConnectOption  ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed ERROR
>   [01000][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't support the
>   version of ODBC behavior that tha pplication requested (see
>   SQLSetEnvAttr). ERROR [08004][Micro Focus][RUMBA Data
>   Access][S1023934]Data source rejected establishment of connection.
>   APPC Primary RC = Allocation_Error; Secondary RC =
>   Allocation_Failure_No_Retry.

I'm not sure what's going on. I may have messed something up when setting up the DSN on the 32-bit laptop but it looks exactly the same as what I set up on the 64-bit desktop... Is there something different between the 32-bit and 64-bit versions or is there something else going on?

Thanks!

EDIT: I just tried it on another 64-bit desktop and I got the same error. There must be something wrong with how I'm setting up the DSN since I set it up on my machine months ago and could be forgetting something.

EDIT2: I ran Windows Update on the desktop where everything worked on and now it doesn't work there either. Is it possible a buggy Windows Update could be causing my issues?

EDIT3: I was asked in the comments to enable tracing and see what happens. Skimming through it, here are a few notable messages:

> EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)

and:

> EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)

Everything else looks like it exits with a status of 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)

Comment: May be you need 32-bit driver for your 32-bit machine?

Comment: are you using the same driver (other than 32/64 bit) on both systems?  It doesn't appear that you're using the standard ODBC driver provided by IBM i Access for Windows.

Comment: @Charles - The driver is labeled "RUMBA AS/400 Optimized Server (32-bit)".

Comment: @T.S. - The laptop had the driver pre-installed by our IT staff. It's labeled 32bit but I don't know how to make sure it's the exact same version as the one on my 64bit machine.

Comment: I just tried it on another 64-bit machine and am still getting the error. I think that means I'm doing something wrong when setting up the DSN...

Comment: Sam, if you ask for tutorials, people will close your question because it becomes off topic - you can google for it yourself. I was thinking along these lines - your 64 bit machine can use 64 or 32 bit driver. Try to find download for the driver you use and see what you get. If they have both, 64/32 bit versions, use x64 on your machine as ling as your software is compiled `AnyCPU` or 'x64'. This is another interesting thing, how your soft is compiled. Shouldn't be matter since you use ODBC. Better yet, find something other than ODBC driver, like direct connect driver.

Comment: Like many, I don't know RUMBA. I'd be concerned about the `APPC` ref in the error. Do you connect to the same server for success and failure?

Comment: I suspect that the successful machine has something installed that allows the (apparently) needed comm function. But also, the `Data source rejected establishment of connection.` error might indicate that the server is filtering different remote connections.

Comment: Wow! So.... I just ran updates on the working desktop and now it's producing the same error as all the other machines. Is it possible that this is all related to a buggy update?

Comment: Probably not. I'd more likely suspect that the installed driver is obsolete and should be replaced or upgraded at least. I'd still be nervous about any current driver referencing `APPC`.

Comment: It's not a 32/64-bit issue, since the application got an error back from the driver. If it was, the application would have gotten an error back from Driver Manager, something like this: `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application`

It looks like the driver is an ODBC 2.0 driver due to the `The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that tha pplication requested (see SQLSetEnvAttr).` message, though I'm unsure if that's the problem. You could try enabling tracing and see what returned that error.

Comment: I put this down for a while but now the project is picking back up and I need to get it resolved. @KevinAdler - I'm updating my original post with the tracer information.

Comment: Is there some reason you're forced to use this Rumba ODBC instead of the proper i Series .Net driver?

Comment: Perhaps almost guaranteed that the driver is long out of date since it references "APPC" and the "optimized" server. Try an actual DB2 for i ODBC driver first.

Comment: Show some code and tell us exactly which odbc driver you are using please. Without code I'm just guessing, but from the error it looks rather clear to me: Your applications tries to set ODBC Version to 3.8, but the driver you are using supports only 3.0. This is the first thing an application does after allocating the environment handle: Setting the ODBC version, using SQLSetEnvAttr. If that fails, all subsequent calls fail. Was it ever working? Did you use a different ODBC driver then?

Comment: @topshot - It was given to me as "the most up-to-date driver". Apparently most here disagree.

Comment: @TheIronCheek I'd never use ODBC if there is one from the db vendor at a higher level (ie, OleDB or ADO.Net) unless that vendor ceased supporting it for some reason (ie, .Net 2.0 only). Even though you somehow solved your problem with a C++ update (???), I'd still update to a better driver. ODBC will give you the least performance and compatibility.

Comment: @topshot: Note that OLE DB is dead. Microsoft announced that SQL Server Denali will be the last one supporting a OLE-DB provider, from then on Microsoft recommends to use ODBC. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2011/08/29/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by installing this [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347&cm_mc_uid=40094057503214673004758&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1467751978).

According to Microsoft,

> A security issue has been identified leading to a vulnerability in MFC applications that are built with Visual Studio 2005 and ship the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package.

Why installing a security patch (rather than a bug fix patch) solved this is beyond me...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12914471)

Comment: The link doesn't answer the question, it links to a file. The text provided here answers the question to say that a Visual C++ 2005 SP1 update solved the problem. I added a bit more info anyway, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using ODBC Administrator, turn on tracing. Try your application and look at the log file for SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION. You should see something like this:

```
odbct32w        fc0-1ad0    ENTER SQLSetEnvAttr 
        SQLHENV             0x007A1DE0
        SQLINTEGER                 200 <SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION>
        SQLPOINTER                 3 <SQL_OV_ODBC3>
        SQLINTEGER                   0 

odbct32w        fc0-1ad0    EXIT  SQLSetEnvAttr  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLHENV             0x007A1DE0
        SQLINTEGER                 200 <SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION>
        SQLPOINTER                 3 <SQL_OV_ODBC3>
        SQLINTEGER                   0
```

The difference will be that yours is returning SQL_ERROR instead of success. Check what the third parameter is (in my case `SQL_OV_ODBC3`). Most likely whatever version your application is setting is newer that what your ODBC driver supports. You'll need to refrain from using newer ODBC features or upgrade your driver to something one that supports a higher level of ODBC.

Comment: That bit in my log file looked exactly the same as yours does.

Comment: Looking back at your message I see that it's actually complaining about SQLSet**Connect**Attr, not SQLSet**Env**Attr. (you could have formatted the error messages a little better) Look through the SQL.LOG and find which SQLSetConnectAttr is returning SQL_ERROR and you can then see which attribute it's trying to set. For more information about the connection attributes available, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713605(v=vs.85).aspx